# Can I change a continent bonus in my current game in Xcom 2?

Tags: xcom-2

There are 11 continent bonuses but only 6 continents. The bonuses are assigned randomly when starting a new game.

I don't want to restart my game to get the bonuses I want, can they be changed by any other way (save editor, changing game ini files)?

Comment: I know this game is made to be tailored to how _you_ want to play it, but I'd advise against changing that. The reason the devs decided to give you a small random pool (and randomized region connections) is so that there is no "one true way" to play the game that has been minmaxed based on a fixed world map.

Comment: I dont want to waste another week of building up my army from nothing just to get the option to add a third upgrade to my weapons, I would rather just change a few variables somewhere. I also want to be able to replace upgrades and sims.

Comment: Consider getting this mod: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=626023136 (I have not tested it, but it has more or less the functionality you seek)

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's no saved game editor of which I'm aware.  And those continent bonuses are generated at startup, so I imagine you're stuck.  There *might* be a dev console command to change them, but I very much doubt it.

Regarding the third weapon upgrade option, you may either:

- play as intended (it's present in some campaigns but not in others, so not this time)
- restart and see if you get it
- download a mod for it.  @Sumurai8 put the link above in the comments, but here it is for completeness: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=626023136

It's worth mentioning, as someone who's completed two campaigns and is halfway through two more (only one of which had Armed to the Teeth) that it's completely unnecessary and fairly overpowered below Legend difficulty.  That said, if you want to have it, go get it.  I personally think it's not well balanced with other continent bonuses, so I won't judge.